# Drupal 8 - Broken default image link in view

Tags: drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal and I've been given a project to fix a couple of bugs on...

I've got a view with several fields, it displays OK when there is a picture but when there is no picture (and thus the need to display a default picture), then a broken image link appears...For some reason the path points to a different directory...

This works:

```
<div class="item-header">   <div class="views-field views-field-field-selection-photos">   ...   <div class="content">

        <div class="field field--name-field-photo field--type-image field--label-hidden field--item">  <img src="/sites/default/files/somepicture.jpeg?itok=sJ6SOjXo" width="445" height="334"/>
```

This does not, due to the path pointing to ../sites instead of /sites:

```
<div class="item-header">
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-selection-photos"><div class="field-content"><img src="../sites/default/files/structures/photos/defaultpic.jpg" width="100%" />
```

I've been looking at theming fields but that seems overkill, I wonder if there's a nice and clean way to sort this out rather than override a template or anything else that would seem a bit too much...

Thanks

Comment: do you want to customize the view template?

did you set this `../site`? if yes, where?

Comment: I want to keep the default views, I just want to make that default picture appear. The way it looks is just perfect for me...minus the broken picture, that is!